# Want to Import contacts in REACT JS from all emails such as hotmail and gmail etc with socials such as facebook and twitter etc

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, react-hooks, contacts

I want to import contacts from all emails such as Hotmail and gmail etc with socials such as Facebook and twitter etc, I am aware of some APIs which can import from specific email domain or socials but is there any library which allows me to import all the contacts from a single library (paid or free no problem).

Just want to import contacts from emails or socials not anything else

I am using React Js at the front end and Python as a backend